# How to force JTextPane not to go to next line?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I need to use a `JTextPane` as a `JTextField.`my `JTextPane` goes to new line while the text reaches to its border, but i want it continues the first line and doesn't go to next line.
how to do that?

Comment: I think you'll find [this](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) interesting

Answer (score 1):

A bit dirty, but though:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane ()
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
    {
        Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize ();
        size.width = 1000000;
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize ()
    {
        Dimension size = super.getMaximumSize ();
        size.width = 1000000;
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize ()
    {
        return super.getPreferredSize ();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth ()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
frame.getContentPane ().add (
    new JScrollPane (textPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack ();
frame.setVisible (true);
```

You also need to somehow prevent user from entering line breaks.

Comment: He said `JTextPane`. `JTextPane` doesn't have this.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov a really easier way is what has been said here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/NonWrappingWrapTextPane.htm